# Save file programm Xamarin Mac

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am working with Visual Studio Mac. In documentation on Microsoft Site there were some instructions about calling some commands like "openDocument", "SaveDocument" those call special windows, but how to save the text or other file itself? As i found, usual C# code from Windows sometimes doesn't work in Xamarin correctly.

```
[Export("saveDocumentAs:")]
    void ShowSaveAs (NSObject sender)
    {
        var dlg = new NSSavePanel();
        dlg.Title = "Сохранить текстовый файл";
        dlg.AllowedFileTypes = new string[] { "txt", "html", "md", "css" };

            if (dlg.RunModal() == 1)
            {
                var alert = new NSAlert()
                {
                    AlertStyle = NSAlertStyle.Critical,
                    InformativeText = "Документ успешно сохранён.",
                    MessageText = "Сохранение документа",
                };
                alert.RunModal();
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Saving and Loading Files in Xamarin Forms**

The `System.IO` classes can be used to access the file system on each platform. The `File` class lets you create, delete, and read files, and the `Directory` class allows you to create, delete, or enumerate the contents of directories. You can also use the `Stream` subclasses, which can provide a greater degree of control over file operations (such as compression or position search within a file).

A text file can be written using the `File.WriteAllText` method:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
```

A text file can be read using the `File.ReadAllText` method:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

In addition, the `File.Exists` method determines whether the specified file exists:

```
bool doesExist = File.Exists(fileName);
```

The path of the file on each platform can be determined from a .NET Standard library by using a value of the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration as the first argument to the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method. This can then be combined with a filename with the `Path.Combine` method:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");
```

More info:you can refer to [this document and demo in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=macos)